# Deprecated “natd” and “ipfw” in El Capitan

Tags: network, macos, vpn, sharing

I want to share my internet connection and VPN connection but Tunnelblick/OpenVPN doesn’t play nice with internet connection sharing in OS X.

There was a suggestion on a workaround on how to route all traffic over VPN as per this post: [Using (and sharing) a VPN connection on your Mac](http://rodrigo.sharpcube.com/2010/06/20/using-and-sharing-a-vpn-connection-on-your-mac/)

The script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

natd -interface tun0
ipfw -f flush
ipfw add divert natd ip from any to any via tun0
ipfw add pass all from any to any
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

I am not a UNIX expert – so I am just wondering if anyone can help me with the alternative for the above deprecated commands please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it and it seems sharing VPN connection in El Capitan is so much easier than it seems.

In `Preferences -> Network` click on `+` and add a VPN (PPTP or L2TP)

In `Preferences -> Sharing`

1. Select (do not check yet), from the `Share your connection from` choose VPN connection previously created.
2. From `To computers using` select `Wi-Fi` if you connect your computer to internet with Ethernet cable or select `Ethernet` if you connect your computer to internet with Wi-Fi.
3. You can change `Wi-Fi Options` from bottom left button.
4. Now Check the Internet Sharing from the left menu, and click `Start`
5. Every time you connect the VPN a network will be created and lets you connect to it with any device and use the VPN on you Mac.

Comment: That feature has always been around -- even when the original article was written. That article is specifically about how to setup the internet sharing so that it routes traffic over a tunnelblick style VPN which unfortunately the built in GUI didn't do then, and still doesn't do in Capitan so this does not answer the question asked.

Comment: I myself asked the question and the answer is OK with me. I wanted to share the VPN connection and it did do that.